# Github Actions self hosted local macOS machine iOS build failing with "The device is passcode protected"

Tags: ios, github-actions, fastlane, github-actions-self-hosted-runners, fastlane-gym

I'm using GitHub self hosted actions to run on my local dev machine to save the free credits when my machine is running. It works most of the time but sometimes it gets stuck with this error:

```
▸ Compiling CapacitorCamera_vers.c
▸ Compiling CapacitorCamera-dummy.m
▸ Compiling CameraPlugin.m
▸ Linking CapacitorCamera
2023-04-03 08:35:49.523 xcodebuild[36930:562246]  DTDKRemoteDeviceConnection: Failed to start remote service "com.apple.mobile.notification_proxy" on device. Error: Error Domain=com.apple.dtdevicekit Code=811 "Failed to start remote service "com.apple.mobile.notification_proxy" on device." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x6000037782d0 {Error Domain=com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain Code=-402653158 "The device is passcode protected." UserInfo={MobileDeviceErrorCode=(0xE800001A), com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace=(
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001124acb1c DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 300
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001124b90c4 __63-[DTDKRemoteDeviceConnection startFirstServiceOf:unlockKeybag:]_block_invoke + 376
    2   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001124b8944 __48-[DTDKRemoteDeviceConnection futureWithSession:]_block_invoke_3 + 28
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001124aec58 __DTDKExecuteInSession_block_invoke_2 + 48
    4   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001124ae358 __DTDKExecuteWithConnection_block_invoke_2 + 216
    5   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001124ae250 __DTDKExecuteWithConnection_block_invoke + 116
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000190906504 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000190915a9c _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
    8   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000106753150 DVTDispatchBarrierSync + 148
    9   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010672e288 -[DVTDispatchLock performLockedBlock:] + 60
    10  DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001124ae148 DTDKExecuteWithConnection + 200
    11  DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001124aeb00 DTDKExecuteInSession + 228
    12  DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001124b87a0 __48-[DTDKRemoteDeviceConnection futureWithSession:]_block_invoke_2 + 128
    13  DVTFoundation                       0x0000000106752428 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 16
    14  DVTFoundation                       0x0000000106752e94 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 152
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001909049dc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000190906504 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
    17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000019090dbbc _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 672
    18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000019090e73c _dispatch_lane_invoke + 436
    19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000019091934c _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 652
    20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000190a8a100 _pthread_wqthread + 288
    21  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000190a88e20 start_wqthread + 8
), DVTRadarComponentKey=261622, NSLocalizedDescription=The device is passcode protected.}}, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Please check your connection to your device., DVTRadarComponentKey=261622, NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to start remote service "com.apple.mobile.notification_proxy" on device.}
▸ Compiling ByteowlsCapacitorOauth2_vers.c
▸ Compiling ByteowlsCapacitorOauth2.m
▸ Compiling ByteowlsCapacitorOauth2-dummy.m
▸ Linking ByteowlsCapacitorOauth2
▸ Generating 'CapacitorCamera.framework.dSYM'
▸ Generating 'ByteowlsCapacitorOauth2.framework.dSYM'
▸ Touching CapacitorCamera.framework (in target 'CapacitorCamera' from project 'Pods')
```

I'm using Fastlane to automate this build process. I thought maybe the simulator had to be open during the build but that didn't make a difference.

I notice in xcode my real (network connected) device is locked. But I'm not sure why xcodebuild would be trying to use my real device during the build process?

[image: ss]

Edit: If I unpair my device to take it out of the equation it now fails with an unhelpful error. Note it builds fine in xcode on the same machine.

```
Compiling Main.storyboard
▸ Compiling LaunchScreen.storyboard
▸ Compiling App_vers.c
▸ Linking App
▸ Processing Info.plist
▸ Running script '[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks'
▸ Generating 'App.app.dSYM'
    Run script build phase '[CP] Copy XCFrameworks' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'FBSDKCoreKit_Basics' from project 'Pods')
    Run script build phase '[CP] Copy XCFrameworks' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'FBAEMKit' from project 'Pods')
    Run script build phase '[CP] Copy XCFrameworks' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'FBSDKCoreKit' from project 'Pods')
    Run script build phase '[CP] Copy XCFrameworks' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'FBSDKLoginKit' from project 'Pods')
** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-fclsinyvecksxwgujqmhxodzehpd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/App.build/Release\ Dev-iphoneos/App.build/Script-9592DBEFFC6D2A0C8D5DEB22.sh (in target 'App' from project 'App')
(1 failure)
[09:57:45]: Exit status: 65

[!] Error building the application - see the log above
npm ERR! Lifecycle script `native:deploy:ios:development` failed with error: 
npm ERR! Error: command failed
```